# Active record find_by_sql, object field return nil in the first time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, find-by-sql

I run the following code in rails console:

```
functions = Function.find_by_sql("Select * from functions where active = 1 and role_id =1")
```

It returns:

```
[#<Function id: 5355, display: "New User", module_name: "Users Management">]
```

When I get the display field:

```
functions[0].display
```

It returns nil value:

```
#<Function:0x7f714011e870>=> nil
```

get the module names:

```
functions[0].module_name
```

outputs:

```
"/users/new"
```

get the display field again:

```
 functions[0].display
```

Now it is correct

```
 "New User"
```

This is function.rb

```
# == Schema Information
# Schema version: 20120327101526
#
# Table name: functions
#
#  id              :integer(4)      not null, primary key
#  display         :string(255)
#  module_name     :string(255)

class Function < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :role
end
```

Can somebody explain to me why functions[0].display returns nil in the first time query?

Comment: what is the output of `functions[0]`?

Comment: the output of functions[0] is:     #<Function id: 5355, display: "New User", module_name: "Users Management">

Comment: can you include the `function.rb` model code in your question thanks